# Why is this variable returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var place = "mundo"["Hola", "Ciao"];
```

Why does this return undefined? Just because it is garbage?

Comment: "mundo" is string .. `"mundo"[0]` will works

Comment: Could this be an attempt at JSON like `var place = {"mundo":["hola", "ciao"]};`

Answer (score 5):

That is perfectly valid JS, though it doesn't do what you expect.

`place` is initialized to the `'Ciao'` property of `String('mundo')`. Since it doesn't exist, it is initialized to `undefined`.

**The tricky part:**

`"Hola","Ciao"` is using the comma operator, evaluates `"Hola"`, evaluates `"Ciao"` and returns `"Ciao"`

`[...]` in this case is property access

`"mundo"[]` `"mundo"` is converted to a String object to access the property on it.

**Proof:**

```
var place = "mundo"["Hola", "toString"];
console.log(place) // function toString() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 3):

The array operator on a string object will either try to index into the string and return a specific character from that string (on some JS implementations) or it will try to lookup a property on that object.  If the index is a number, some JS implementations (I think this is non-standard behavior) will give you that character from the string.

```
// returns "m" in Chrome
"mundo"[0]

// returns undefined
"mundo"[9]
```

But, an array index that isn't a number will try to look for that property on the string object and your particular value won't be found on the string object and thus you get `undefined`.

```
// does a property lookup and returns "function toString{[native code]}
"mundo"["toString"] 

// returns undefined - no propery named foo
"mundo"["foo"]
```

So, since there is no property on the string that resembles anything in `["Hola", "Ciao"]`, you get `undefined`.  Technically, the browser is actually looking for the `"Ciao"` property when you give it this and because that property doesn't exist, you get `undefined`.

---

In a weird test, you can run this code to sort of see what's going on:

```
var str = new String("mundo");
str["Ciao"] = "Hello";
alert(str["Hola", "Ciao"]);    // alerts "Hello"
```

Working demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/e6R8a/

---

This all makes me wonder what in the heck you are actually trying to do that comes up with this odd construct.

Comment: +1 for the correction of the string index behavior. Note the OP is aware "it is garbage".

Comment: Added a jsFiddle demo to my answer that kind of shows what's going on.